# When using minikube, how do we access Kubernetes API from external host?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, cicd

While using Jenkins (hosted externally) to deploy in Kubernetes (using minikube), I have installed the kubectl plugin and set the build env with credentials, server url context etc. But while invoking the build job it fails and console output shows the following error

```
    + ./kubectl get pods
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.29.4:8443: i/o timeout
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
[kubernetes-cli] kubectl configuration cleaned up
Finished: FAILURE
```

Here is the snapshot of my build job configuration

[image: Build Env screenshot]

I tried to set the proxy with available port "8082" but when I curl the API it works with "localhost" on same system where minikube is hosted, which indeed I don't want since Jenkins is externally hosted and it should be able to do the api call with IP address of the minikube cluster.

Any idea what is the problem here? Please share the insight/solution.

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly did you get it started and how is it supposed to work? From what you wrote, Jenkins is on a different network and your Minikube is on the local network.

Comment: @Mikołaj Głodziak you are right. I can use the port forward to access the cluster, but that's not a reliable way for sure.

Comment: @Wytrzymały Wiktor no updates yet. Abandoning the setup!